# ApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver : Failed to retrieve properties for resource:Docker Resource

Tags: java, docker, spring-batch, openshift, spring-cloud-dataflow

Hi I'm running Spring Cloud Data Flow Server  (v2.6.2-SNAPSHOT) in openshift environment. I get the NullPointerException every time I schedule or launch a task from SCDF saying `Failed to retrieve properties for resource`. I'm registering My Springboot batch application as Docker image in SCDF. Below is the Exception trace.

Though it's not affecting the task execution in anyway, It generates of lots of logs in SCDF container. And we usually run our batches every 10 minutes.

I searched about this issue and found links to github where it says it's fixed in older version. But not sure how it's happening in V2.6.2. I hope this is the issue the ticket was about.

Github ticket: [ApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/pull/1186/commits/6e49a93fbac61a5a4b7c505d555f0b05ec8f93cb)

Let me know if there's anything I can do fix this issue.

```
2020-12-10 15:29:05.134  WARN 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-6] ApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver : Failed to retrieve properties for resource:Docker Resource [docker:docker-registry.default.svc:5000/test-batch/batch-job:latest]

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.configuration.metadata.container.DefaultContainerImageMetadataResolver.getRegistryRequest(DefaultContainerImageMetadataResolver.java:162)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.configuration.metadata.container.DefaultContainerImageMetadataResolver.getImageLabels(DefaultContainerImageMetadataResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.configuration.metadata.BootApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver.resolvePropertiesFromContainerImage(BootApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.configuration.metadata.BootApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver.listProperties(BootApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver.java:141)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.controller.WhitelistProperties.qualifyProperties(WhitelistProperties.java:62)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.TaskServiceUtils.mergeAndExpandAppProperties(TaskServiceUtils.java:164)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.TaskAppDeploymentRequestCreator.createRequest(TaskAppDeploymentRequestCreator.java:118)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService.executeTask(DefaultTaskExecutionService.java:284)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$422cda43.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2bbaf819.executeTask(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.controller.TaskExecutionController.launch(TaskExecutionController.java:170)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ForwardedHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ForwardedHeaderFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an authorization issue based on what I see from the [code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/eb565737957fbd6de37c058087c3a3c1f7574e3f/spring-cloud-dataflow-configuration-metadata/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/configuration/metadata/container/DefaultContainerImageMetadataResolver.java#L162).
Check if you have the correct auth config as mentioned [here](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/2.6.x/feature-guides/general/application-metadata/#using-metadata-container-image-labels)